# Why isn't addClass working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm including the **navbar** of my website with php so I can't use **class="active"** to indicate the active tab of my navigation bar separately. So I decided to use a little jquery code to add **active** class on the corresponding tab. But for some reason its not working and I can't find any solution.

Here is my jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav_about").addClass("active");
});
</script>
```

And here is my **navbar** html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-sticky">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
   <a class="navbar-brand hidden-sm" href="#myPage">Logo</a>
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <li cl ass="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li id="nav_about"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> TEAM <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="teachers_panel.php">Teachers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="students_panel.php">Students </a></li>
                    </ul></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Events <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Upcoming Events</li>
                        <li><a href="sidebar-right.php">1st ACC IT Carnival 2016</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Past Events</li>
                        <li><a href="cgc.php">Inter House Cyber Gaming Competition 2015</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tbtt.php">Take Back the Tech </a></li>
                        <li><a href="gbb.php">Google Bus Bangladesh at ACC </a></li>
                        <li><a href="moz.php">Mozcoffee at ACC </a></li>
                        <li><a href="hoc.php">Hour Of Code </a></li>
                        <li><a href="hjfp.php">Club Hangoutat JFP </a></li>
                    </ul></li>  
                    <li><a href="u_cons.php">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="u_cons.php">Get Involved</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                </li>
            </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Edit:

I've Edited the mistake which are not ending the **$(document).ready(..** and not putting a **$** before **(document)**.

Comment: Missing closing `)` after document.ready.

Comment: @showdev Thank you :D it was certainly a silly mistake. It's funny how sometimes you can't detect some obvious mistakes.

Comment: You have also some mistakes in your html code, check my code below. Too many 'li' closing tags

Comment: @KamilMierzyński Thank you very much for pointing out my typos. They are working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some typos in your HTML and JS code. Check this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav_about").addClass("active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-sticky">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
   <a class="navbar-brand hidden-sm" href="#myPage">Logo</a>
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <li cl ass="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li id="nav_about"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> TEAM <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="teachers_panel.php">Teachers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="students_panel.php">Students </a></li>
                    </ul></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Events <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Upcoming Events</li>
                        <li><a href="sidebar-right.php">1st ACC IT Carnival 2016</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Past Events</li>
                        <li><a href="cgc.php">Inter House Cyber Gaming Competition 2015</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tbtt.php">Take Back the Tech </a></li>
                        <li><a href="gbb.php">Google Bus Bangladesh at ACC </a></li>
                        <li><a href="moz.php">Mozcoffee at ACC </a></li>
                        <li><a href="hoc.php">Hour Of Code </a></li>
                        <li><a href="hjfp.php">Club Hangoutat JFP </a></li>
                    </ul></li>  
                <li><a href="u_cons.php">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="u_cons.php">Get Involved</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>                    
            </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `$(document)` instead of `document` in jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav_about").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

</script>
And here is my navbar html:

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-sticky">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
   <a class="navbar-brand hidden-sm" href="#myPage">Logo</a>
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <li cl ass="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li class="active" id="nav_about"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> TEAM <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="teachers_panel.php">Teachers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="students_panel.php">Students </a></li>
                    </ul></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Events <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Upcoming Events</li>
                        <li><a href="sidebar-right.php">1st ACC IT Carnival 2016</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Past Events</li>
                        <li><a href="cgc.php">Inter House Cyber Gaming Competition 2015</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tbtt.php">Take Back the Tech </a></li>
                        <li><a href="gbb.php">Google Bus Bangladesh at ACC </a></li>
                        <li><a href="moz.php">Mozcoffee at ACC </a></li>
                        <li><a href="hoc.php">Hour Of Code </a></li>
                        <li><a href="hjfp.php">Club Hangoutat JFP </a></li>
                    </ul></li>  
                    <li><a href="u_cons.php">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="u_cons.php">Get Involved</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                </li>
            </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked after putting a $ and ending the $(document) (as $showdev pointed out) properly.